# How do I compare these two strings in python?

Tags: python, string

In crawling `RSS` feed, I do not want duplicate items added to my list. The problem is that some duplicates are not detected by my `if title not in mylist` line because they are slightly different. Nonetheless, these two news items are basically the same. Take a look at this two.

`"Kom igjen, norsk ungdom, de eldre trenger oss!"` and 
`"Kom igjen norsk ungdom, de eldre trenger oss"`

As you see, the first one has comma after `Kom igjen` and the second one doesn't and has an exclamation mark at the end.

Since there is no other unique id that makes individual items unique, I do not know how to detect duplicates like the one above.

Comment: Have you tried using a `filter()` to remove the punctuation?

Comment: so, where do you draw the line... are you looking to find out how to compare two strings ignoring punctuation (and probably whitespace and case)?

Comment: I will try ```filter()```one out now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python has a SequenceMatcher build-in:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
SequenceMatcher(None, "Hello you!", "Hello you").ratio()
0.9473684210526315
SequenceMatcher(None, "Apple", "Orange").ratio()
0.18181818181818182
```

So you can loop over all and compare the ratio against some threshold.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.translate` method before you add your news to your list to remover punctuations :

```
>>> s1.translate(None, string.punctuation)
'Kom igjen norsk ungdom de eldre trenger oss'
```

In that case you'll compare your texts based on theirs alphabets.

In python 3 you can do :

```
>>> s1.translate(dict.fromkeys(map(ord,string.punctuation),None))
'Kom igjen norsk ungdom de eldre trenger oss'
```

Comment: Seems to switch to all lower or upper case and removing any whitespace could also be a good idea?

Comment: I got error in Python 3. I think ```string.punctuation``` is not valid in Python 3.

Comment: @JeffBridgman Yeah, indeed! based on the type of news it could have another options